# React component not displaying if dynamically generated list items empty

Tags: javascript, web-applications, reactjs

I have a react component that contains a child list of components created using a map:

```
var listItems = model.arrayItems.map(function(item) {
    return(<ChildComponent item={item}></ChildComponent>)
}, this);
```

And the component's render function then adds this list of child components:

```
return (
    <div>
        <h1>My items:<h1>
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    </div>
);
```

The problem is that the react component is not showing up in my browser when listItems is empty. However, if I resize the browser window, the component does show up. Does anyone have any advice on what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Can you give a demo/fiddle that demonstrates this? What browser, resize it in what way? It doesn't look like there's enough information here.

Comment: +1 for more info. You could also try setting listItems to en empty string and if that renders your problem is probably the ChildComponent component and you should post that code here too.

Comment: It did turn out to be an issue with the child component. More detailed summary in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it did turn out to be an issue with ChildComponent. In fact, it seems to have been a CSS issue.

ChildComponent itself had a nested set of dynamically generated list items. These grandchild components had the CSS property for width set to 100%. Changing this property to "auto" fixed the issue.

My understanding is that when transitioning to a state in which the top-level list is empty, and given the way React is managing unmounted components, the grandchild component's CSS style of 100% (of parent element) somehow confuses the browser's rendering because its parent component is no longer mounted. If anyone knows the cause of this behavior in more depth, it would be great to hear a deeper explanation of this.